# Postback Causing Page to Load as if for the First Time

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I am using:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

to force a postback on my web page.  However, the path of execution in the code is as if the page were loading for the first time.  How do I cause just an ordinary postback?

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

EDIT:

This post seems to be attracting a lot of negativity.  I got this method from a Stock Overflow post after a Google search for forcing a **postback**.  So the downvoters should probably take out their frustrations on that post instead of mine.

To clear up some of the misapprehensions about my question:

I have an event Button_Click that contains logic in the method body -- obviously.  However the flow of execution of the code goes like this:

Button_Click --> Page_Load (IsPostBack == true) --> Button_Click body --> execution ends.

So my problem is that none of the logic in the body of Button_Click is showing up on the page because the postback is done before any of the code in the body of Button_Click is executed.

EDIT:

Here is the event:

```
protected void RedoEdits_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Goes to Page_Load here with IsPostBack == true
    string trendsFileLocation = currDir + "\\" + reportDir + "\\" + trendsFile;
    string messagesFileLocation = currDir + "\\" + reportDir + "\\" + messagesFile;
    if (File.Exists(trendsFileLocation))
    {
        File.Delete(trendsFileLocation);
    }
    if (File.Exists(messagesFileLocation))
    {
        File.Delete(messagesFileLocation);
    }
    trendsXML.Clear();
    editMode = "redo";
}
```

Code snippet for IsPostBack == true:

```
if (editMode.Equals("redo"))
{
    editMode = "";
    ViewReport_Click(null, null);
}
```

The code snippet never gets exercised because the postback happens first, skips the snippet because editMode != redo, then finishes with the body of RedoEdits_Click which finally sets editMode == redo but since the postback has already happened we don't get to ViewReport_Click.

And btw, editMode is a session variable so it persists.

Comment: Hmm...trying to force postbacks from the server usually isn't a good idea.  Can you tell us a little more about what you're trying to do?  Maybe we can suggest a better way.

Comment: Show the code that isn't working with the explanation what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @walther: Thanks.  See the edit to my original question.

Comment: Looking at it, but still missing the code :-) Can you show where and how do you subscribe to button click event + relevant parts of the code not working?

Comment: What does ViewReport_Click(null,null) do? Or better, what do you want it to do?

Comment: It generates and displays the report.  It doesn't user either of the parameters (object sender, EventArgs e) so calling it with nulls is not a problem.  The report is editable by the user.  It has several fields for user input which it takes and displays and then removes the input controls.  ViewReport_Click would regenerate the page with the input controls displayed again.  This works.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, hopefully it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed the page reload to restore my original, unedited, HTML.  The process of editing the table replaced some InnerHTML and I needed to start over to redo the edits.  So I just moved the logic necessary for redoing the edits in the code for IsPostBack != true and stayed with Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl).  Works like a charm.

Comment: Glad you got it working, but I really wouldn't advise anyone to use redirect method this way. I consider this to be a bad practice and a poor design. You've just plagued the flow of the application and created really unnecessary redirect, but hey, it's your app, whatever suits you :-)

Answer (score 2):

That's because redirecting DOES load the page as if for the first time.  It's not posting back at all.  This may be in an event handler like a button click, but once you redirect in that postback event handler, it is no longer in the postback of the same instance, you're reloading the page from scratch.

Example

```
private void MyButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   lblStatus.Text = "Button Clicked!";  // still within a postback
   Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);  // now leaving the postback.  At this point, exexution stops and the page is loaded from scratch, as if we're not in a postback.

   lblStatus.Text = "Done posting back";  // This code will never execute.,  Response.Redirect throws a System.ThreadAbortException, and by default, code execution stops once Response.Redirect happens.

}
```

If you want to trigger a true postback without then loading the page from scratch, put a button or some control on the screen and use that to trigger a real postback, and don't call Response.Redirect().

---

Added because of hte comment below:

Familiarize yourself with the [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).  If you hace things happening in Page_Load that you don't want to occur within the postback, then you should surround them with

```
if(!Page.IsPostback)
{
  // stuff that should only happen on initial load here.
}
```

OR consider doing those things in a different event.  For example, if you're creating controls on teh fly, it should be done in Page_Init because it happens BEFORE the ViewState is applied.  If done this way, the controls are created in Page_Init on each postback, and THEN the values are applied from teh Viewstate, and THEN you reach Page_Load, where you can work with them.

Comment: My problem is that I have an event and, whenever it is triggered, the postback happens first and then the event logic.  I need it to happen in the other order.

Comment: Are you referring to the Page_Load being executed?  If so, that happens first no matter what.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: No, I'm talking about the postback.  And I am using if(!Page.IsPostback) for the first page load.

Comment: @Kevin - that doesn't make sense to me. What do you mean by "the postback"? The postback to me means that the page posts back to itself and that isn't represented in the page life cycle.

Comment: @PHeiberg, that doesn't make sense to anyone, but obviously some people like to downvote when you say that out loud.

Comment: Here's the flow of execution: Button_Click --> Page_Load (IsPostBack == true) --> Button_Click body is executed and control ends at the end of Button_Click.  So none of the logic in Button_Click's method body is shown on the page since it does the postback first and then executes the method body.

Answer (score 1):

You can't force a postback from your code-behind. How would you do that? Postback occurs when you click a button for example. Even if it was possible to force it from code-behind (surely there's a way), what would you achieve by that? Just call a method you want, don't do stupid things like this.

Postback = posting data/request back to the same page. Redirecting obviously won't work.

**EDIT** based on OPs edits:

You need to rethink your workflow, so maybe do it like this:

```
protected void RedoEdits_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Goes to Page_Load here with IsPostBack == true
    string trendsFileLocation = currDir + "\\" + reportDir + "\\" + trendsFile;
    string messagesFileLocation = currDir + "\\" + reportDir + "\\" + messagesFile;
    if (File.Exists(trendsFileLocation))
    {
        File.Delete(trendsFileLocation);
    }
    if (File.Exists(messagesFileLocation))
    {
        File.Delete(messagesFileLocation);
    }
    trendsXML.Clear();

    ViewReport_Click(null, null);
}
```

It really isn't a good idea to try to emulate the postback.

Or, maybe even better approach - define a new Event, let's say EditModeActive (or whatever name you want), that will fire up every time you assign editMode = "redo". Then just subscribe to this event and do whatever you wish.

Comment: I was not the downvote but can you explain this line please? `You can't force a postback from your code-behind.`

Comment: @Duane, postback is when you have a page, user does something (clicks a button for instance), causing a postback. When you're in code-behind though, it's an utter nonsense to cause a postback. How would you do that? You'd post from where to where? From code-behind to itself without leaving the server?

Comment: That makes sense. I suppose your button/markup causes the postback, which your code behind running on the server processes with the new input/hidden values? So causing a postback from the code behind makes no sense in this regard, am i right?

Comment: @Duane, precisely... Post back - posting data/request back to the same page. But when you're already on the server side, it's really weird to try to emulate that and I'm completely baffled why someone needed to downvote my answer without any explanation. I love this community, very helpful and positive. I can admit when I'm wrong, but can't do that when no one explains my mistake...

Comment: +1 particularly for "It really isn't a good idea to try to emulate the postback."

Answer (score 0):

Response.Redirect() isn't cause any postback becouse it only sends a simple GET request to the server.